# Disallowing Free Shipping Rule if promo reduces cost to below minimum amount

Tags: promotions

We have a free shipping promo on international orders $100 and over.  We also have free shipping on all domestic orders.  My question being, on international orders how can I set up the rule so that if the total is under $100 after the discount, they don't get free shipping?  Ex:  We run a Holiday Promo for 20% off store wide, item is regularly $100, with the promo the new total is $80.  Since that new total is under $100, I would like the free shipping rule to be unavailable to this customer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the minimum amount for the free shipping method to $100 and only mark the international countries to be allowed to use this method. You'd need to grab one of the other modules, flat rate for example, in the system to be used for the domestic shipping.

If you are already using the flat rate for regular shipping or somesuch, there's plenty of downloadable shipping modules that allow similar behavior.

See: http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/admin_shipping_freemethod.jpg